# iOS 10 - uploaded build showing success in xcode but its not available in the app store content?

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

**Xcode** upload showing success while upload but not showing error message in the app store content page

Note: already requested more information to apple team

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the reference of the video, I resolved:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/709/?time=1754

I missed NSCameraUsageDescription field in the info.plist

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html

Answer (score 0):

Please check your email, iTunes connect page.

App Store team should request resolving ITMS-XXXXX some issue.

It is showing success when uploading binary but after processing in iTunes connect, they request resolving specific issue number ITMS-XXXXXX

for example

```
Dear Developer,
We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "SUPER GREAT APP". Please correct the following issues, then upload again.
ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).
Best regards,
The App Store Team
```